# Handling a input with HTML inside its value (using jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-entities

I created a small function similar to a edit-in-place plugin.

What it does:

- gets the html content of a element on click: `var editable = $(this).html();`
- creates the text input field (or gets it if it exists):

  ```
  var input = ($('input', this).length > 0) ? $('input', this) : $('<input type="text" value="' + editable + '" />'),
  ```
- replaces the element text with the input: `$(this).empty().append(input);`

This works but only if the editable text doesn't contain non-encoded HTML characters.

If it has HTML characters like `<` `>`, they get converted in the 2nd step to HTML code, and mess up the input element...

I tried to escape them by using:

`editable = $('<div/>').text($(this).html()).html()`

but then I get a text input with escaped HTML lol :)

What can I do?

Comment: The character that really matters is '"' since it closes your value="" attribute. You need to be very careful about XSS injection however.

Comment: yes `"` seems to be the issue, because all text after that doesn;t show..

Comment: Do you want your input textbox to just display the content including all the HTML tags? Or do you want to remove the HTML tags and display just the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can HTML-escape a string so that it can be included in an HTML attribute value like this:

```
var escaped = string.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/'/g, '&#39;').replace(/"/g, '&#34;');
```

Comment: that worked thanks. I have now problems in a different place, but I think I can fix them :)